# Eigen matrix assignment taking a long time -- is there a solution?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I'm trying to create quite large matrices (to store point data) in an Eigen matrix in the following way

```
void MyFunction(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived1>& X) {

    // Create empty matrix
    Eigen::Matrix3Xf Q = Eigen::Matrix3Xf::Zero(3, X.cols());
```

Where X.cols is around 300,000. This is taking a LONG time when I'm stepping through the code in debug mode, making it difficult to test my code. Is there a way to assign the matrix more quickly? I was thinking about passing a pointer to a float array using the Eigen::Map class. Any insight greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by taking LONG time?? Here, with debug info and no compiler optimization, this step is taking about 2ms... Don't tell me you are stepping inside this assignment?  Any debugger allows  to step over a statement...

Comment: Hmmm, on my system we're talking closer to a minute or two. Will have a closer look to see why it's taking so long.

Comment: Ok, I've recreated the core bit of code in a separate project and it runs (as ggael) suggests in a couple of milliseconds. I suppose this means it's something to do with my implementation specifically. Does anyone have any ideas of what _might_ cause this slowdown? Any particular inclusions? This is happening right at the entry point to the class so there's not even that much code that's run before it.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake on my part, debugging my code in release mode (vs2013). Be sure your settings are in debug if you want to step through the code. Changing this sped everything up to a few ms as ggael suggests.